# Swapping from XMLHttpRequest() to Fetch() and still get boolean output

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch, output, undefined

I know there's zillions of ways of doing this ...

So I have this function which returns me boolean upon HEAD file check status using XMLHttpRequest.

```
const urlToFile = "shorturl.at/devIK";
function doesFileExist(urlToFile) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
  xhr.send();
  return xhr.status == "404" ? false : true;
}
```

**However, deprecated.**

Now trying to build and understand how to handle data output from fetch API. Turns out I'm not able to get desired output.

```
const urlToFile = "shorturl.at/devIK";
function doesFileExist(urlToFile) {
  return fetch(urlToFile, { method: 'HEAD' })
   .then(res => { res.ok ? true : false; })
   .then(fileExistResult => fileExistResult.boolValue())
   .catch(err => console.log('Error: ', err));
}
```

-->

```
doesFileExist(urlToFile) == true ? do_this : do_that;
```

I keep getting *undefined* from console.log
If you could help me out on this one... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from what is actually asked, conditional operator is not purposed to replace `if ... else` structure, it's an operator returning a value, not a control flow statement.

Comment: doesFileExist() now returns a Promise, not a Bool value